# Attempted import error: 'useDispatch' is not exported from 'react-redux'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to update my store in redux via useDispatch method, but I am getting a message like that:

> Attempted import error: 'useDispatch' is not exported from 'react-redux'.

I am using this method for call the action to update my store.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { loggedInAction } from './redux';

const userInfo = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const loggedIn = user => dispatch(loggedInAction(user));
```

Comment: which version of react-redux are you using?

Comment: it is react-redux v `7.0.3`

Comment: import {useDispatch} from 'redux-react-hook';

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit (Sept 15, 2019):**
Install `react-redux@7.1.1` or `react-redux@latest`

Find latest version here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux?activeTab=versions

---

Install `react-redux` version: `7.1.0-rc.1`
or do `npm install react-redux@next`

Answer (score 4):

I just forget to give the curly braces over {useDispatch} and that's why I was facing this error!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use v7.1.0, current release candidate is `v7.1.0-rc.1`

See [this page](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks)

> Note: The hook APIs listed in this page are currently a release candidate! We encourage you to try them out in your applications and give feedback. We hope that the APIs are stable at this point, but be aware that there may still be changes before final release.
>
> These hooks were first added in v7.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the latest version of react-redux

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the version of  react-redux
You can solve this problem by using

```
npm install react-redux@latest
```

For more information check the github page:
[check this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4200)